# Showing Filename Differences in List Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, collectors

I am trying to compare files and my solution works with folders that have a small amount of files in them like 10 but not folders with like over 200 filenames in them. The last part of my codes comes back NULL or `Results = [ ]` usually the text file(s) name is in here that shows the difference between both folders any help is appreciated. The problem is the last part of my code

```
package nameCompare;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662384/comparing-file-names
// http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/3-java-program-can-list-all-files-given-directory.html

public class fileNameCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                             // first directory path here
        String path1 = "C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/ADP/MagMediaAfter";
        //String path1 = "C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/FolderA";

        // second directory path here
        String path2 = "C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/ADP/MagMediaAfter";
        //String path2 = "C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/FolderB";


        File folder1 = new File(path1);
        int fileCount = folder1.list().length;

        File folder2 = new File(path2);
        int fileCountTwo = folder2.list().length;


        File[] listOfFiles1 = folder1.listFiles();
        File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles();

        //we'll need these to store the file names as Strings
        ArrayList<String> BeforeMM = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> AfterMM = new ArrayList<String>();

        //get file names from directory
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++)
        {
            if (listOfFiles1[i].isFile())
            {
                BeforeMM.add(listOfFiles1[i].getName());//wow
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; i++)
        {
            if (listOfFiles2[i].isFile())
            {
                AfterMM.add(listOfFiles2[i].getName());//seriously wow
            }
        }

            // Number of Files in each Folder or Directory
            System.out.println("Files in FolderA / BeforeMM ----> " + fileCount );
            System.out.println("Files in FolderB / AfterMM -----> " + fileCountTwo );
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");

            System.out.println( "Size/Number of Array Elements BeforeMM -----> "+BeforeMM.size() );
            System.out.println( "Size/Number of Array Elements AfterMM  -----> "+AfterMM.size() );
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");

            System.out.println("Before Media Folder Conatins----> " + BeforeMM );
            System.out.println("After Media Folder  Conatins----> " + AfterMM );
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");
            //this is where problems start
            List<String> result = AfterMM.stream().filter(elem -> !BeforeMM.contains(elem)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println("Result: File(s) present in After BUT NOT BeforeMM folder:\n" + result);
            // Result equals Test2.txt

            /*// Remove all elements in BeforeFolder from AfterFolder
            BeforeMM.removeAll(AfterMM); 
            // Show results
            System.out.println("Result: " + AfterMM);
            */




    }




}
```

Comment: lol those code comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of improvements and simplifications we can make to your code, first you might build your paths using [`System.getProperty("user.home")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) and the [`File(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) constructor. Next, you can collect your list of files with streams. Then you can use `removeAll` to build your final `List`. Like,

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
File adp = new File(desktop, "ADP");
File folder1 = new File(adp, "MagMediaBefore");
File folder2 = new File(adp, "MagMediaAfter");
List<String> beforeMM = Stream.of(folder1.listFiles()) //
        .filter(File::isFile).map(File::getName) //
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> afterMM = Stream.of(folder2.listFiles()) //
        .filter(File::isFile).map(File::getName) //
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Number of Files in each Folder or Directory
System.out.println("Files in FolderA / BeforeMM ----> " //
        + beforeMM.size());
System.out.println("Files in FolderB / AfterMM -----> " //
        + afterMM.size());
System.out.println("------------------------------------");

System.out.println("Before Media Folder Conatins----> " //
        + beforeMM);
System.out.println("After Media Folder  Conatins----> " //
        + afterMM);
System.out.println("------------------------------------");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(afterMM);
result.removeAll(beforeMM);
System.out.println("Result: File(s) present in After BUT NOT " //
        + "BeforeMM folder: " + result);
```

Note that you are currently reading the **same folder** in `folder1` ***and*** `folder2`. Also, please follow Java variable naming conventions (`beforeMM` and `afterMM`, yours' looked like class names).

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler than that... You can simply use `removeAll()`:

```
List<String> copied = new ArrayList<>(AfterMM); //copy the list
copied.removeAll(BeforeMM);// this removes from copied everything that's in BeforeMM (if it's also in copied).
```

And then to print them all you can simply do:

```
System.out.println("Result: File(s) present in After BUT NOT BeforeMM folder:"+copied);
```

And that will print the contents of `copied`, which contain everything that is in `AfterMM` but isn't in `BeforeMM`

Also, as was pointed out, you are listing the same folders:

```
"C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/ADP/MagMediaAfter";
```

And then your result would always be `[]`. You'll get other results if you give `path1` and `path2` different values.

I don't think you can have `*` in a filename, but a `-` shouldn't cause any trouble.

Comment: Okay I want to make sure i have this right. To Print out the results I would say[          System.out.println("Result: File(s) present in After BUT NOT BeforeMM folder:\n" + BeforeMM); ] Correct?

Comment: Okay Thanks also if the filename includes special characters will that make a difference?

Comment: @JonathanHofler depends on the special characters. Which chars?

Comment: and just so you know, Elliot's answer is much better than mine. I mean he addresses **everything**, so you should upvote his answer.

Comment: Like * and - in the filename?

Comment: Also so that I am clear I am comparing filenames from one folder to another to printing out the difference However I am still getting 256 for results when i do System.out.println("Result Files" + result.size());

I should not be getting the same number back it should be less

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148698/discussion-between-itamarg3-and-jonathan-hofler).

Comment: or anyone looking at this post question. I have another question if the index of 2017 changes lets say next year to 2018 I can change the number correct? Basically index is saying read everything up to this point right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem in your code,I had tried the code for two directories which had around 1K files.See at anypoint the BeforeMM is always the superset.the result can be empty in two cases

- Files in BeforeMM == Files in AfterMM
- Files in AfterMM = Files in BeforeMM - few files missing